# Play: extract the WebJar contents to a certain path

Tags: playframework, sbt, webjars

According to the [WebJars documentation](https://www.webjars.org/documentation)

> Play automatically extracts the WebJar contents and makes them available via the Assets controller.

Is there a way to change that?

Instead of `/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css` I would need `/myProject/assets/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the prefix in the URL route, then you can change your static asset controller's route in the `conf/routes` file.

Comment: you are right, after trying some paths in the routes - it works now -thanks.